# I am stuk with email templet for outlook

Tags: html, email, outlook

I am created HTML newsletter page with image mapping and it's work fine but when I copy the content from the browser to paste on windows outlook, it's perfectly posted here but image mapping does not work here.
I am also tried adobe photoshop slice tool to add URL's on each slice and save as the web, which creates one image folder where are all slices and one HTML file. When I open this HTML file in the browser, it looks perfect, but again when I copy all content and paste it, on outlook it shows a white line on the image.
I want an image which has multiple links to different areas of the image and sends it to the client via my outlook account. How do I this?

There is my HTML code with area mapping

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body><div align="center">
     <img src="https://d2slcw3kip6qmk.cloudfront.net/marketing/press/images/template-gallery/newsletter-classroom@2x.jpeg" alt="Smiley face" height="100%" width="80%" usemap="#Map"> 
     </div>
     <map id="Map">
          <area shape="rect" coords="14, 13, 460, 162" target="_blank" href="http://securitylinkindia.com/may17report.html" title="new" alt="">
<area shape="rect" coords="18, 189, 154, 604" target="_blank" href="http://securitylinkindia.com/may17whitePaper.html" title="new" alt="">
<area shape="rect" coords="166, 190, 308, 441" target="_blank" href="http://securitylinkindia.com/may17dahua.html" title="new" alt="">
<area shape="rect" coords="322, 190, 462, 438" target="_blank" href="http://securitylinkindia.com/may17report.html" title="new" alt="">
<area shape="rect" coords="168, 455, 461, 603" target="_blank" href="http://securitylinkindia.com/may17whitePaper.html" title="new" alt="">
     </map>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title></title>
    </head>
    <body><div align="center">
      <img src="https://d2slcw3kip6qmk.cloudfront.net/marketing/press/images/template-gallery/newsletter-classroom@2x.jpeg" alt="Smiley face" height="100%" width="80%" usemap="#Map"> 
      </div>
      <map id="Map">
         <area shape="rect" coords="14, 13, 460, 162" target="_blank" href="http://securitylinkindia.com/may17report.html" title="new" alt="">
    <area shape="rect" coords="18, 189, 154, 604" target="_blank" href="http://securitylinkindia.com/may17whitePaper.html" title="new" alt="">
    <area shape="rect" coords="166, 190, 308, 441" target="_blank" href="http://securitylinkindia.com/may17dahua.html" title="new" alt="">
    <area shape="rect" coords="322, 190, 462, 438" target="_blank" href="http://securitylinkindia.com/may17report.html" title="new" alt="">
    <area shape="rect" coords="168, 455, 461, 603" target="_blank" href="http://securitylinkindia.com/may17whitePaper.html" title="new" alt="">
      </map>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I need a solution as soon as possible. Thank you for contribution....

Answer (score 0):

The best way will be to slice the image individually and put them in seperate table cells. This way you can give each a link.

Image map doesn't work well if you pasting it into outlook.

Comment: Thanks but I used that and there is only one problem is to not a good looking template.